# I can't uninstall an application, i accidently deleted the uninstall.exe file for it

Tags: windows, storage, uninstall

I'm trying to free up space in my PC and I tried deleting the files for an application rather than clicking uninstall (Yes, i know it was a dumb decision), and now I'm unable to uninstall it, the windows uninstaller says "cannot find *appname*unstll.exe."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try to force install it again. And then uninstall.

Answer (score 3):

Like Romeo said, you can install it again (make sure to put it in the same directory as it was previously) and then you should get an uninstaller.

Alternatively, you can try using the windows app uninstaller, though it may not be there depending on how much of the program you have already deleted.

To use the uninstall manager:

1. Open control panel
2. Under programs go to "Uninstall a Program"
3. You will see a list of your programs, navigate to the program you want (there is a search bar in the top right)
4. Select the program you want and press uninstall.
5. This should uninstall the program without the uninstaller.